# Is there any formula to calculate the no of passes that a Quick Sort algorithm will take?

Tags: quicksort

While working with Quick Sort algorithm I wondered whether any formula or some kind of stuff might be available for finding the no of passes that a particular set of values may take to completely sorted in ascending order.

Is there any formula to calculate the no of passes that a Quick Sort algorithm will take?

Comment: On average, it's `O(nlog n)`; in the worst case, it's `O(n²)`. Is that what you're looking for? Or do you want to calculate for *specific* cases, given a known amount of data?

Comment: Are you looking for something different from _O(N log(N)) best case, O(N^2) worst case if you pick the pivot naively_? In what way would what you're looking for be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any given set of values will have a different number of operations, based on pivot value selection method, and the actual values being sorted.

So...no, unless the approximations of 'between O(N log(N)) and O(N^2)' is good enough.

That one has to qualify the average versus worst case should be enough to show that the only way to determine the number of operations is to actually run the quicksort.